# Switch JSON key in for loop (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

I'm working with the Wordpress JSON API plugin, and custom fields.

Here's the relevant section of the JSON file:

```
{
  "post": {
    "custom_fields": {
      "tracks": [
        "4"
      ],
      "tracks_0_name": [
        "First Track"
      ],
      "tracks_1_name": [
        "Second Track"
      ],
      "tracks_2_name": [
        "Third Track"
      ],
      "tracks_3_name": [
        "Fourth Track"
      ]
    },
}
```

So immediately, I know how many tracks there are from the `tracks` key. I'm then running this (where `trackCount = tracks`):

```
for( var i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {

    newTrack = '<li>';
    newTrack += '<div class="trackNum">'+(i+1)+'</div>';
    newTrack += '<span>';
    newTrack += result.post.custom_fields.tracks_X_name;
    newTrack += '</span>';
    newTrack += '</li>';

    $('.tracklist .main').append(newTrack);
}
```

That `tracks_X_name` needs to change each time based on the `i` variable, and I can't for the life of me figure out how. Any thoughts?

*Note: The code **is** working, if I run this with `tracks_0_name` I get 4 tracks with the same title, but count, etc. is all fine. It's just a case of targeting the correct key on each instance of the loop.*

Comment: Switch to the index name: `newTrack += result.post.custom_fields["tracks_" + i + "_name"];`

Comment: AHA! I'd tried this, but kept the period between "fields" and the opening square-bracket :facepalm:. Works a charm, feel free to add as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer:

Switch to the index name:

```
newTrack += result.post.custom_fields["tracks_" + i + "_name"];
```

Hard to do with all Dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to change the key from dot notation to something like this:

```
newTrack += result.post.custom_fields['tracks_'+i+'_name'];
```

However, I would recommend changing how you structure your data:

```
{
"post": {
    "custom_fields": {
      "tracks": [
        "4"
      ],
      "tracks_0_name": [
        "First Track"
      ],
      "tracks_1_name": [
        "Second Track"
      ],
      "tracks_2_name": [
        "Third Track"
      ],
      "tracks_3_name": [
        "Fourth Track"
      ]
    },
}
```

This method can cause errors or undesired behavior if the track count is different from the actual number of tracks. If I were to write this out, I would do it more like this:

```
{
  "post": {
    "custom_fields": [
      "tracks_0_name",
      "tracks_1_name",
      "tracks_2_name",
      "tracks_3_name"
    ]
  }
}
```

And for the JQuery:

```
var len = result.post.custom_fields.length;
for( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    newTrack = '<li>';
    newTrack += '<div class="trackNum">'+(i+1)+'</div>';
    newTrack += '<span>';
    newTrack += result.post.custom_fields[i];
    newTrack += '</span>';
    newTrack += '</li>';

    $('.tracklist .main').append(newTrack);
}
```

Comment: The `tracks` value gets updated every time a new track is added, so it's **always** gonna be the same as the track total. Changing the structure of the JSON isn't really an option (this is default from WP JSON API plugin). Plus, *Twisty*'s comment has solved the issue. Cheers anyhow!!